# Как склонять названия сёл?

Tags: орфография, склонение

Как правильно написать сочетания типа «в селе Ново-Александровка/ке,  Ломовка/ке, Челново-Дмитриевка/ке, Лапуховка/ке»?

Answer (score 1):

Похожий вопрос уже был. Названия городов, сел, деревень, поселков, усадеб, выраженные склоняемым существительным, *как правило*, согласуются в падеже с определяемым словом, например: *в городе Москве, у города Смоленска, над городом Саратовом; в деревню Дюевку, через хутор Подбанку, в селе Ильинском*.
**НО** есть случаи, когда вышеприведенные **названия не согласуются с определяемым словом, если они выражены:**
1) словосочетанием: *в городе Кривой Рог, из села Чистый Ключ*;
2) формой множественного числа: *из города Черкассы, через хутор Большие Кузьмичи*;
3) **именами собственными, род которых не совпадает с основным понятием**: *в городе Ровно, у деревни Берестечко, в селе Углянец*;
4) именами собственными на -ово(-ёво), -ыно(-ино): *в городе Иваново, из поселка Пушкино*.

Все приведенные вами примеры относятся к случаю, когда род имени собственного не совпадает с родом определяемого слова: названия женского рода, а определяемое слово - среднего. Кроме того, одно из названий представляет собой сложное слово, первая часть которого - имя собственное на -ово (Челново-Дмитриевка).
И еще. Я, конечно, не настаиваю, но проверьте правильность написания слова Л**а**пуховка (по правилам должно быть Л**о**пуховка, если только указанное вами написание не закреплено официально).
Таким образом, писать нужно так: *в селе Ново-Александровка, Ломовка, Челново-Дмитриевка, Л**о**пуховка*.