# «В селе Белое-6» или «В селе Белом-6»? Стоит ли склонять название села, если название идет вместе в цифрой?

Tags: склонение, топонимика

« В селе Белое-6». Стоит ли склонять название села, если название идет вместе в цифрой?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, дело не в цифре. Вопрос о склонении названий сел среднего рода на *-e*, да еще если присутствует родовое слово *село*, — спорный. 
Смотри на этом сайте:

[Склонение названия села](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/413245/%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0)

[Как склонять названия сёл?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4503/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%91%d0%bb)

[Склоняется ли название села Столбище](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443710/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%89%d0%b5)

Цифра — маленький довесок на той чаше весов, где написано "не склонять". Мое предпочтение: "**В селе Белое-6**". Но это не говорит, что склоняемый вариант ошибочен.

Дополнение (подсказано Una Nana @UnaNana).
Грамота.ру [советует](http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_1_toponimy/):

> Итак, запоминаем азбучную истину № 1.
>   Азбучная истина № 1. Географические названия славянского происхождения, оканчивающиеся на -ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно, не склоняются в сочетании с родовым словом: из района Люблино, в сторону района Строгино, к району Митино, в городе Иваново, из деревни Простоквашино, до края Косово.

Comment: Ведь оба слова среднего рода! Значит, склоняется!

Comment: "Однако в современном русском языке бнаруживается тенденция к несклоняемости приложений-топонимов среднего рода, оканчивающихся на -е, -о: между селами Молодечно и Дорожно, недалеко от села Миронежье, в городе Видное."  (@ЕкатеринаКаштанова) (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/413245/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0)